# Why is Matthew Modine first in the credits of Stranger Things S02 EP09?

Tags: credits, stranger-things

We see Matthew Modine (Dr Brenner) two times in Stranger Things S02 and he's first on the opening credits of the EP09.

My only theory is maybe he accept to join the casting only if he's first on the credits.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: "First on generic"? Do you mean "first in the opening credits"? I've never heard the word "generic" used to refer to a credits sequence before.

Comment: @F1Krazy In Belgium we use the word "generiek" to describe the opening credits, I assume his native language uses a similar one. In French it's "générique".

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thanks for clearing that up, I wasn't aware of that. Would it be acceptable to edit the question to change "generic" to "opening credits", just to clarify things for non-Francophone users?

Comment: @F1Krazy edited, it looks like a mistranslation. Questions and answers should be in proper english.

Comment: yes i'm french, and yes, opening credits is better than generic :D ty for the editing my post

Comment: And about the possible duplicate, I do not think it's, because this would wean than Modine is the more prestigious actor or or that he embodies a very important character. I think some characters are more important...